# Category.php loads first before page.php?

Tags: categories, pages, seo

I've got a problem with the following:

I made a category called app-functions, when viewing my domain.com/app-functions/ it opens up the category-app-functions.php instead of page-app-functions.php. Does anyone know why this happens?

Also.. with the view of SEO, page.php is more important then category.php.. right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress select template, following its [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) logic. What you have that is category archive, templates for individual pages are never considered for it.

> Also.. with the view of SEO, page.php is more important then category.php.. right?

PHP template file is entirely back-end concepts, it doesn't have anything to do with SEO inherently.